# How to resolve intentional circular dependency in angular provider?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

For this provider, I would like to take an existing injectiontoken if exists, if not, use specified provider.

This  is my code:

```
    providers: [
        {
            provide: DesignerRecoveryComponentStore,
            useFactory: (injector: Injector) => {
                return injector.get(
                    DesignerRecoveryComponentStore,
                    new DesignerRecoveryComponentStore(
                        injector.get(Store),
                        injector.get(Actions),
                        injector.get(NgZone),
                        injector.get(DesignerActionDispatcher),
                        injector.get(PresentationRecoveryService),
                        injector.get(Router),
                        injector.get(PadsDialogService)
                    )
                );
            },
            deps: [Injector]
        }
    ]
```

It checks if a provider exists for DesignerRecoveryComponentStore (a subclass), if it exists, we return that, if it does not exist I create a new instance of the main class.

I get circular dependency errors in the log.

How to do this correctly?

I tried replacing the class I'm searching for with an interface, but that didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.

The issue was that I was trying to reuse a container in another container. The solution was to create a new container that injected the class

```
[ container A injects A]    [ container B injects B]
                \                /
                 \              /
            [ component A requires A or B ]
```

Instead of

```
       [ container A injects B ]
                    |
[ container B searches B or injects A]
```